# SRS (RTMP) authentification with PHP error

Tags: php, http-live-streaming, rtmp, simple-realtime-server

So I recently started to work with SRS (https://github.com/ossrs/srs) and I already had a lot of issues figuring out how to make FFMpeg work.

But now it's different I need to do basic authentification (https://github.com/ossrs/srs/wiki/v3_EN_HTTPCallback).

So I had the idea to do a PHP code that simply returns the code 200 and a value of 0 when the user is correct and 404 when it doesn't work.

For me, it isn't working and I am not able to get help for now in this repo did anyone here used it or have any idea on how I should do that?

Here is my PHP code (it's an example for the moment) :

```php
<?php
$username = $_POST["name"]; # in our current example, this will be 'john'
$password = $_POST["psk"]; # in our current example, this will be 'supersecret'
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");

$valid_users = array("john" => "supersecret",
                     "winnie" => "thepooh",
                                         "batman" => "nananananananana");
$fp = fopen('test.txt', 'w');
fwrite($fp, "test $username $password posted data $postdata");
fclose($fp);
header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
if ($valid_users[$username] == $password) {
  http_response_code(200); # return 201 "Created"
        echo intval(false);
} else {
  http_response_code(404); # return 404 "Not Found"
}
?>
```

Here are the errors I get when I try to use it.

```
[2020-04-23 09:35:16.634][Trace][3921][473] connect app, tcUrl=rtmp://192.168.1.10:1935/live/livestream?name=john&psk=supersecret, pageUrl=, swfUrl=rtmp://192.168.1.10:1935/live/livestream?name=john&psk=supersecret, schema=rtmp, vhost=195.201.153.98, port=1935, app=live/livestream, args=null
[2020-04-23 09:35:16.634][Trace][3921][473] protocol in.buffer=0, in.ack=0, out.ack=0, in.chunk=4096, out.chunk=128
[2020-04-23 09:35:16.724][Trace][3921][473] client identified, type=fmle-publish, vhost=195.201.153.98, app=live/livestream, stream=, param=?name=john&psk=supersecret, duration=0ms
[2020-04-23 09:35:16.726][Warn][3921][473][11] use public address as ip: 192.168.1.10
[2020-04-23 09:35:16.728][Warn][3921][473][11] http: ignore on_close failed, client_id=473, url=http://195.201.153.97/test.php, request={"action":"on_close","client_id":473,"ip":"178.211.242.54","vhost":"__defaultVhost__","app":"live/livestream","send_bytes":3655,"recv_bytes":3430}, response=
, code=404, ret=4005
[2020-04-23 09:35:16.728][Error][3921][473][11] serve error code=4005 : service cycle : rtmp: stream service : check vhost : rtmp: callback on connect : rtmp on_connect http://192.168.1.10/test.php : http: on_connect failed, client_id=473, url=http://192.168.1.10/test.php, request={"action":"on_connect","client_id":473,"ip":"192.168.1.11","vhost":"__defaultVhost__","app":"live/livestream","tcUrl":"rtmp://192.168.1.10:1935/live/livestream?name=john&psk=supersecret","pageUrl":""}, response=
, code=404 : http: status 404
thread [3921][473]: do_cycle() [src/app/srs_app_rtmp_conn.cpp:210][errno=11]
thread [3921][473]: service_cycle() [src/app/srs_app_rtmp_conn.cpp:399][errno=11]
thread [3921][473]: stream_service_cycle() [src/app/srs_app_rtmp_conn.cpp:462][errno=11]
thread [3921][473]: check_vhost() [src/app/srs_app_rtmp_conn.cpp:586][errno=11]
thread [3921][473]: http_hooks_on_connect() [src/app/srs_app_rtmp_conn.cpp:1243][errno=11]
thread [3921][473]: on_connect() [src/app/srs_app_http_hooks.cpp:83][errno=11]
thread [3921][473]: do_post() [src/app/srs_app_http_hooks.cpp:504][errno=11](Resource temporarily unavailable)
[2020-04-23 09:38:40.582][Trace][3921][474] API server client, ip=187.8.182.21
[2020-04-23 09:38:40.582][Trace][3921][474] HTTP API GET http://192.168.1.10:9090/setup/index.jsp, content-length=-1, chunked=0/0
[2020-04-23 09:38:40.984][Warn][3921][474][104] client disconnect peer. ret=1007
```

Maybe you are better than me to understand the logs but I truly don't know what I am doing wrong.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after digging during a lot of hours. This is the solution if finded (but i didn't finded a way to correctly say no) so if you enter anything else than 0 the server will do an error (not by crashing) and simply refuse the connection wich works but isn't clean.

```php
<?php
echo "0";
$code = 200;
    // clear the old headers
    header_remove();
    // set the actual code
    http_response_code($code);
    // set the header to make sure cache is forced
    header("Cache-Control: no-transform,public,max-age=300,s-maxage=900");
    // treat this as json
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $status = array(
        200 => '200 OK',
        400 => '400 Bad Request',
        422 => 'Unprocessable Entity',
        500 => '500 Internal Server Error'
        );
    // ok, validation error, or failure
    header('Status: '.$status[$code]);
    // return the encoded json
    return json_encode(array(
        'status' => $code < 300, // success or not?
        'message' => $message
        ));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in order to successfully identify a client, you must provide a specific `something` response, otherwise the SRS will reject the client. This allows you to filter out unauthorized clients. Please refer to the [Callback Error Code](https://ossrs.io/lts/en-us/docs/v5/doc/http-api#error-code) documentation for more information.

> Note: The `on_publish` callback can also be utilized for advanced security measures, enabling you to `allow` or `deny` clients based on their IP address, token in the request URL, or any other client-related information.

The term `something` in this context refers to:

- HTTP/200, which indicates a successful HTTP response.
- `AND` a response with an integer value of 0, or a JSON object containing a field with code 0.

For example:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 1
0
```

Or:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 11
{"code": 0}
```

You can run the sample HTTP callback server [here](https://ossrs.io/lts/en-us/docs/v5/doc/http-callback#go-example) by executing:

```
cd srs/trunk/research/api-server
go run . 8085
```

> Note: There are other demo API servers available, such as [Go](https://ossrs.io/lts/en-us/docs/v5/doc/http-callback#go-example), [Node.js](https://ossrs.io/lts/en-us/docs/v5/doc/http-callback#nodejs-koa-example), and [PHP](https://ossrs.io/lts/en-us/docs/v5/doc/http-callback#php-example).

By running the example, you will be able to determine the appropriate response format.